# Ratio test with $\limsup$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.In my course it's written that the series converge is $$\limsup_{n\to\infty }\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|<1$$

**Q1)** All examples I know, the $\lim$ is enough. Do you have an example where the lim doesn't exist but the limsup <1 ?

**Q2)** Let $$a_n=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3^n}&n\in 2\mathbb N\\ 
\frac{1}{4^n}&n\in 2\mathbb N+1
\end{cases}.$$

Since $\sum_{n\in 2\mathbb N}a_n$ and $\sum_{n\in2\mathbb N+1 }a_n$ converge, normally $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_n$ converge, right ?

But,  $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\begin{cases}\frac{3^n}{4^{n+1}}&n\in 2\mathbb N\\\frac{4^{n}}{3^{n+1}}&n\in 2\mathbb N+1 \end{cases}$$
and thus by ratio test,
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty }\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{4^n}{3^{n+1}}=+\infty $$ therefore it diverge.

What's the problem here ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\limsup $ theorem is not "if and only if." The sequence diverges if $\liminf \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|>1$. This test is inconclusive when:

$$\liminf \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\leq 1\leq\limsup \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$$

which is your case.

Answer (score 2):

For 1), we can do this: Let $(b_n)_{n=2}^\infty$ be the sequence $1/2, 1/4, 1/2, 1/4, \dots.$ Define $a_1 = 1, a_{n+1} = b_na_n$ for $n>1.$ Then $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is just the sequence $b_n.$ Thus $\limsup a_{n+1}/a_n= 1/2,$ but $\lim a_{n+1}/a_n$ fails to exist.